# Navigating from VB.NET code to C# code problem

Tags: vb.net

There seemes to be a consistent problem with the following situation:

Say you have a VS2008 solution, consisting of a (say console) application written in vb.net, and a class library written in c#. The application references the class library 
project.

This, of course, complies and works well. However, when you right-click (in the vb.net application code) a function prototype/object type defined in the class library, and select "Go to definition", the object browser opens providing you with the the list of methods available for the class the class library consists of. BAD. However, if you try to do the same when both the application and cl are in c#, this works just fine and you navigate driectly to the relevant function/class.GOOD.

Known issue? Solvable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# -->Go to Definition ==> VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041647/c-sharp-go-to-definition-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a project reference instead of a DLL reference? A project reference should take you to the actual relevant code in the other assembly.

Answer (score 0):

[It's a known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/501303/find-all-references-go-to-definition-do-not-work-across-vb-c-in-same-solution#), the workaround are two: use `ctrl+,` or use some plugin that add this function, like resharper.