# C# -->Go to Definition ==> VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-to-vb.net

I have a solution in VS 2010.

There are two DLL projects: one UserControl in C# WPF (myCSharpUC) and other - WinForm UserControl in VB.NET (myVbUC)

Actually in myCSharpUC I have an instance of myVbUC:

```
myCSharpUC {
    private MyVbUC vbControl;

    ...
    somemethod()
    {
       vbControl.MyProperty
    }
}
```

Is there a way to "navigate to definition" of `MyProperty` directly? (*actually only **metadata** is displayed*)

Comment: I don't know if it actually helps you, but have a look at following links: http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2010/09/why-does-go-to-definition-and.html and http://johnson1965.blogspot.com/2007/07/visual-studio-2005-go-to-definition-i.html

Comment: gorohoroh comment below about Resharper is one way.  I'm also looking for any other solution to this problem, but if you install resharper it's "go to definition" will work between c# and vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/501303/find-all-references-go-to-definition-do-not-work-across-vb-c-in-same-solution#), the workaround are two: use `ctrl+,` or use some plugin that add this function, like resharper (that will add this function in the `F12`).

Answer (score 2):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)'s [Navigate to External Sources](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/10/resharper-5-overview-navigation-to-and-within-external-sources/)?

Comment: I have no "external" sources... a little small solution with 2 userControls and a Form.