# Mixing C# and VB.NET projects = broken "Go to definition"

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a large-ish solution, with C# and VB.NET projects mixed. Whenever I try to “Go to definition” on a class, property or method that’s defined in the other language, Visual Studio just takes me to the Object Browser, which is pretty annoying. Same for debugging: I can’t step into a project that's written in the other language.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have project refs or Assembly refs?

Comment: Are all projects targeting same Framework version?

Comment: Release or debug build?  (just tested -- shouldn't matter)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# -->Go to Definition ==> VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041647/c-go-to-definition-vb-net)

Comment: Both release and debug build has this behaviour. In fact, I'm pretty sure VS always has behaved like this.

Comment: Seems like a rather common problem and has been taken up on SO many times, found 2-3 dupes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1260157/3482953.aspx) seems like a reported bug

[Find all references / go to definition do not work across VB/C# in same solution](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/501303/find-all-references-go-to-definition-do-not-work-across-vb-c-in-same-solution).

Quote:

> The project-to-project reference between a C# and VB project is treated like a file assembly reference where all symbols are treated as if coming from metadata.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I feared. Fingers crossed they'll fix it at some point. :)

Answer (score 16):

I have this problem too. As workaround I use **Navigate to (CTRL + comma)** instead of **Goto Definition**.

Comment: That's pretty neat. I've gotten so used to just slapping F12 that I forgot about the Navigate To feature in VS2010. Thanks! :)

Comment: nice work, I thought I was a level 70 programmer orc, but the fact that I didn't know about this feature has led me to believe otherwise.